# Add Value to Retrieved SOQL Query Object

Tags: apex

I am trying to add a boolean value to my retreived object before i pass it back to my JavaScript Helper.

```
public static List<Policies__c> getContacts(String rId){

    List<Policies__c> policyList = new List<Policies__c>();

    policyList = [SELECT "Alot of Fields, removed them as they are irrelevent"] ;

     for (Policies__c policy : policyList) {


    List <ContentDocumentLink> fList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :policy.Id];

    Set<Id> documentIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (ContentDocumentLink fls : flist) {
    documentIds.add(fls.ContentDocumentId);
    }

   Integer checkValues = [SELECT COUNT() FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :documentIds AND (File_Type__c = 'Policy Values' Or File_Type__c = 'Annual Values')];

  Boolean backupValues = checkValues > 0;

   }

    return policyList;
}
```

I am stuck on the syntax for adding the Boolean value that i created within the class to the policy record. I have tried the dot notation syntax i usually use in Javascript and tried the add method but i got the Method does not exist for the add method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add arbitrary data points to an sObject. You can populate values only in existing fields of the appropriate data type. For example, if `Policies__c` has a Checkbox field called `Has_Attachments__c`, you can set it

```
policy.Has_Attachments__c = backupValues;
```

You can use the `put()` method when you need to determine the field name dynamically (which does not appear to be the case here):

```
policy.put('Has_Attachments__c', backupValues);
```

Here, it looks like what you need is probably a *wrapper class*. A wrapper class encapsulates an sObject and arbitrary associated data you wish to track with it. An example might look like this:

```
public class PolicyWrapper {
     @AuraEnabled
     public Policies__c policy { get; set; }
     @AuraEnabled
     public Boolean hasAttachments { get; set; }

    public PolicyWrapper(Policies__c policy, Boolean hasAttachments) {
        this.policy = policy;
        this.hasAttachments = hasAttachments;
    }
}
```

then you can create a `List<PolicyWrapper>`, and add each item with its associated extra data points:

```
List<PolicyWrapper> wrappers = new List<PolicyWrapper>();


// ...
wrappers.add(new PolicyWrapper(policy, backupValues));

// ...
return wrappers;
```

There's more information and examples in the [Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm).

Comment: Excellent answer David, thanks